# Want to put images side by side in a container, but cannot get rid of a line break

Tags: css, image, containers, inline, nowrap

I am trying to put image-containers in another container, ultimately it will be many in one row, for now I have four.

My problem is I ultimately want to move them across the screen like a conveyor belt while they still change on mouseover.

So it is important, that the ones that are hidden because of end of screen, are being cut of and do NOT leave the row. I do not understand why even with nowrap they always move to another row.

If someone has a simple trick to make a conveyor belt I would be thankful too. My javascript does not work either.

```
<style>
#container {
background: transparent;
position: relative;
overflow:hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 450px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

}

```
#foto1 {
height: 450px;

display: inline;
vertical-align: top;
float: none;
white-space: nowrap;
content: url("images/ruecken.jpg");
}
#foto1:hover { content: url("images/image-2.jpg");
}
#foto1:active { content: url("images/image-3.jpg");
}

#foto2 {
height: 450px;

 display: inline;
vertical-align: top;
float: none;
white-space: nowrap;
content:url("images/Ruecken.jpg");
}
#foto2:hover { content: url("images/image-3.jpg");
}
#foto2:active { content: url("images/image-4.jpg");
}

#foto3 {
height: 450px;

display: inline;
vertical-align: top;
float: none;
white-space: nowrap;
content:url("images/Ruecken.jpg");
}
#foto3:hover { content: url("images/image-5.jpg");
}
#foto3:active { content: url("images/image-6.jpg");
}

#foto4 {
height: 450px;

display: inline;
vertical-align: top;
float: none;
white-space: nowrap;
content:url("images/ruecken.jpg");
}
#foto4:hover { content: url("images/image-4.jpg");
}
#foto4:active { content: url("images/image-5.jpg");
}

</style>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [Bootstrap Carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

Comment: This is a bad practice css code, use classes instead of ids. You can create a class called .image for instance and assign the style to it, no need to repeat your self. And for the question it self you may use **flex** property on the container

Comment: Thanks Fadifannoun!! It works! I tried with the classes, but then I have trouble assigning different images on hover etc..?!